# Substring and IndexOf and LastIndexOf in c#

Tags: c#, substring, indexof, lastindexof

I have this **string** :

> 464-138234-AVENANCE

And I need this output on three items :

```
 464
 138234
 AVENANCE
```

For first item I have try with success :

```
strMyString.SelectedItem.Value.Substring(0, strMyString.SelectedItem.Value.IndexOf('-'))
```

Output : `464`

I can't to extract the two and three items :

```
strMyString.SelectedItem.Value.Substring(1, strMyString.SelectedItem.Value.IndexOf('-'))
```

The output is :

```
64-
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Comment: `.Split('-')` you get an array from it that will contain all the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  string myStr="464-138234-AVENANCE";
    string[] data= myStr.Split('-');
```

Answer (score 3):

why not?

```
string msg = "464-138234-AVENANCE";
var myArray = msg.Split('-');
```